# mongoose post function error (undefined is not a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

this is the post function, update commented out the date value ,same error

```
function postParty(req, res) {
var Party = new Party();

Party.title = req.body.title;
Party.username = req.body.username;
Party.location = req.body.location;
Party.time = req.body.time;
Party.about = req.body.about;
Party.invites=req.body.invites;
Party.isPrivate = req.body.isPrivate;
//Party.date=Date.now();

Party.save(function (err,party) {
 if (err)
  res.send(err);
  res.json({ message: 'party created!' });
 });
}
```

and this is my schema

```
var PartyScheme = new Schema({
title: String,
username: String,
location: String,
time: String,
//date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
about: String,
invites: [{username: String , user_id: Number }],
isPrivate: Boolean,
 });

var Party = mongoose.model('Party', PartyScheme);
```

url -/partys, postParty ,
and this error on post request 
{
  "code": "InternalError",
  "message": "undefined is not a function"
}

Comment: You shouldn't be overwiting variables like that. Use `var party = new Party()` instead.

Comment: How exactly are you calling/using the `postParty` function? I doubt that this is a Mongoose issue.

Comment: Wild guess: elsewhere in your code, have you defined a variable called `Date`?

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks that fix the problem ,change the party to the lowercase